# vector field on gnuplot with u and v components

Tags: vector, gnuplot, field, numerical-methods

I'm solving Navier-Stokes equation for incompressible fluid flow through a square region with obstacle. As an output I get `X` and `Y` components of velocity as `NxN` matrix each. How to plot vector field for it in gnuplot.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442401/vector-field-using-gnuplot) but I can't understand what values to put for `x, y, dx, dy`.

Can anyone explain how to use my output to plot vector field?

**UPDATE**

I tried doing as @LutzL said, but something seems to be wrong with my code. Is everything alright with this code?

```
int main() {
    ifstream finu("U"), finv("V");
    int N = 41, M = 41;
    auto
            **u = new double *[N],
            **v = new double *[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        u[i] = new double[M];
        v[i] = new double[M];
    }
    double
            dx = 1.0 / (N - 1),
            dy = 1.0 / (M - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            finu >> u[i][j];
            finv >> v[i][j];
        }
    }

    ofstream foutvec("vec");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            foutvec << dx * i << "\t" << dy * j << "\t" << u[i][j] << "\t" << v[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }
    ofstream plt("graph.plt");
    plt << "set term pngcairo"
           "\nset title 'Navier-Stokes Equation'"
           "\nset output 'vec.png'"
           "\nplot 'vec' w vec";
    plt.close();
    system("gnuplot graph.plt");
    return 0;
}
```

As an output I get a bit weird field.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save your result in a text file with  lines

```
x[i]  y[j]  X[i,j]  Y[i,j]
```

for all of the pairs `i,j`. Then use gnuplot with the "traditional" vector field command.

You need only use `using` if you put additional columns into that file, and the vectors to display are not (simply) the 3rd and 4th columns. One use might be that you compute a scaling factor `R[i,j]` to display `X/R, Y/R`. Put that into 5th place

```
x[i]  y[j]  X[i,j]  Y[i,j]  R[i,j]
```

and call with `using 1:2:($3/$5):($4/$5)` to perform the scaling in gnuplot.

---

In the code in the **update** and the resulting image, one sees that the vector field is too large to plot. Scale with `dt` for some reasonable time step, in the gnuplot commands this could be done via

```
dt = 0.01
plot 'vec' u 1:2:(dt*$3):(dt*$4) w vec
```

The incomplete plot hints to an incomplete data file on the disk. Flush or close the output stream for the vector data.

Comment: That looks right. You have a problem with the scaling of the vectors, add `u 1:2:($3/10):($4/10)` (or with a higher factor) to the plot command. And close (to flush) the data stream `foutvec`, it seems that at the time of plotting not all data was written to disk.