# gnuplot vector arrow length and streamlines

Tags: vector, plot, gnuplot, numerical-methods

I have already [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54941564/vector-field-on-gnuplot-with-u-and-v-components) about vector fields in here. Now I want to know a bit more about it.

How can I make it so that each arrow has the same fixed length and define the magnitude of the value by color?

And is it still not possible to plot streamlines in gnuplot? If possible, how can I do that?

For now I have this and need to upgrade it.

```
set term pngcairo
set title 'Navier-Stokes Equation'
set terminal png size 1280,720
set output 'vec.png'
plot 'vec' u 1:2:($3/$5):($4/$5) w vec t 'Vector Field'
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @theozh I've got what I wanted. I want to share my result as it could be useful for someone else.
Now I use these instructions to plot my vector field.

```
reset session
set size square
set palette rgb 33, 15, 10
set term pngcairo
set title 'Navier-Stokes Equation'
set terminal png size 1280, 720
set output 'vec.png'
plot 'vec.dat' u 1:2:(0.08*$3):(0.08*$4):(sqrt($3**2+$4**2)) w vec lw 2 lc palette notitle
```

[image]

Comment: For streamlines you need an ODE integrator. gnuplot has advanced from pocket calculator capabilities to some programming structures, but not to the level of a numerics system like matlab (which in turn incorporated limited CAS capabilities, while the Mathematica CAS incorporated comprehensive numerics capabilities). I do not think that the makers of gnuplot strive to re-invent the likes of octave, mupad etc.

Comment: glad that I could help. Well, you haven't normalized your arrows. On purpose? The magnitude is already shown by the color, so no need to additionally show it by the length of the arrow. In your case the normalization would be `Scaling=0.08` and `...(Scaling*$3/sqrt($3**2+$4**2)):(Scaling*$4/sqrt($3**2+$4**2)):(sqrt($3**2+$4**2))...`.

Comment: @theozh thanks again. it will be a good addition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the same length: simply normalize your vectors.

About the color:
you can add a "column" and the end. The last column will define the color according to a palette.

I don't know about streamlines (what exactly they are and how to possibly realize them).

With the example script:

**Script:** (*Edit: define function for length `L()` to make plot command shorter and clearer.*)

```
### plot with normalized/scaled vectors
reset session

set size square
set samples 25
set palette rgb 33,13,10
set key noautotitle

Scale        = 0.5
L(colX,colY) = sqrt(column(colX)**2+column(colY)**2)

plot [-5:5] '++' u 1:2:(Scale*$1/L(1,2)):(Scale*$2/L(1,2)):(L(1,2)) w vec lc palette
### end of script
```

[image]