# plot streamlines with matplotlib from file

Tags: python, matplotlib, numerical-methods

I've done a lot of things to plot streamlines and came to this. I've [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057828/gnuplot-vector-arrow-length-and-streamlines) about vector fields and found an answer. Now I want streamlines plotted with `matplotlib`. For now, I have output data that I use to plot vector field in `gnuplot`. I've outputted data as `X Y U V` and want to use it for streamlines.

And I don't know how to set output preferences for an image. I have this sample code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

Y, X = np.mgrid[0:1:31j, 0:1:31j]
U = -1 - X**2 + Y
V = 1 + X - Y**2
speed = np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 9))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=3, ncols=2, height_ratios=[1, 1, 2])

# Varying color along a streamline
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
strm = ax1.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, color=U, linewidth=1, cmap='gnuplot')
fig.colorbar(strm.lines)
ax1.set_title('Navier-Stokes Equation')


plt.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('streamlines.png')
plt.show()
```

What to edit to input U and V from file and output it as a formatted image?
[image]

Comment: You can use `x, y, u, v = np.loadtxt('file.txt', unpack=True)` to read the data from a file

Comment: Little vague on the question. Are you asking on how to import data or are you asking something about figure preferences? Also what do you mean with figure preferences?

Comment: @GlobalTraveler I want to import data from file. And when I export the plot into an image, the graph is located only on the top right corner, and elsewhere is empty.

Comment: @Bazingaa solved the first part. The second part  is due to your gridspec. You are specifying a 3 x 3 subplot matrix and plotting it in the middle top. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208826/subplots-overlapping-in-matplot/55209664?noredirect=1#comment97167856_55209664)

Comment: @Bazingaa your suggestion gives an error `ValueError: The rows of 'x' must be equal`